# Alternativas ao método de requisição de páginas por POST

Tags: php, html, post

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web para o meu trabalho. Ele consiste de um dashboard que vai apresentar informações da empresa para os gestores. Nesse contexto, estou tentando otimizar a página buscando o conteúdo adequado de acordo com a modalidade que eu busco. Assim, fiz um menu contendo as três modalidades de ensino que a empresa trabalha: colégio, graduação e pós-graduação. Estava fazendo os botões do menu como formulários que iriam redirecionar para uma página que iria ter uma função que verifica a modalidade enviada via POST. É funcional, contudo sempre que eu tento ir para uma outra página ele acusa que dados do formulário podem se perder e se torna uma coisa incômoda. Desta forma, gostaria de dicas e sugestões de como re/fazer para chegar ao resultado final que almejo sem que tenha essa mensagem do formulário.

Função que retorna página

```
function get_page_modalidade($modalidade = "home"){
    if($modalidade == COLEGIO){
        return print "include './parts/menu-detalhe.php'" ;
    } elseif ($modalidade == "home") {
        return print "include './parts/menu-detalhe.php'" ;
    } elseif ($modalidade == GRAD) {
        return print "include './parts/menu-detalhe.php'" ;
    } elseif ($modalidade == POS) {
        return print "include './parts/menu-detalhe.php'" ;
    } else{
        return "outro";
    }
}
```

Chamamento de função

```
<?php  get_page_modalidade($_POST['modalidade']);?>
```

Botão do menu

```
<li>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="modalidade" value="home">
        <input type="submit" name="home" value="Dashboard" class="btn-block btn btn-focus btn-menu">
    </form>
```

Comment: Coloca o código que se tem....

Comment: Tem algum motivo especial para estar fazendo por POST?

Comment: @Randrade Tem sim. Eu uso o link para identificar o nome da página. Quando uso o GET ele apresenta parâmetros que podem dar erro.

Comment: @MagicHat Acabei de atualizar com os códigos principais.

Comment: Estou começando a entender, fala uma negócio, depois que vc faz a checagem o que acontece, qual a continuação do código ?

Comment: Também não entendi porque usar post pra um link simples, o que vai acontecer se o usuário adicionar a página nos favoritos? favoritos não guarda os dados enviados via post.

Comment: @MagicHat a intenção é fazer algo semelhante ao que o Wordpress faz com a função get_template_part(). Eu quero que quando eu clicar no link do menu eu não tenha que redirecionar para uma página para cada item, mas sim carregar os módulos de acordo com a requisição. Em um template comum, quando eu faço um link com a tag <a> ele redireciona para uma página em específico. Se eu tenho 10 itens no menu, vou ter que fazer 10 páginas. A forma que eu quero fazer é redirecionar para uma única página e uma função carregar os módulos que cada modalidade pré-definida tem.

Comment: @Washingtondacosta Eu queria buscar o conteúdo das páginas de acordo com a modalidade de ensino. Um botão com a modalidade "colegio" vai passar via POST para a página em PHP que analisa a modalidade e busca o módulo correto, sem ter que criar uma página para cada módulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Rafael, a alternativa que recomendo ao método HTTP POST é o HTTP GET, respondendo o mais diretamente ao título da sua dúvida.

Pelo que entendi, a sua dificuldade não é gerenciar os módulos e sim apenas evitar o aviso do navegador sobre revisitar uma URL em método HTTP POST, que é quando *sempre que eu tento ir para uma outra página ele acusa que dados do formulário podem se perder e se torna uma coisa incômoda.* conforme você explicou.

Vou usar um exemplo similar: tenho um site de e-commerce e tem um formulário método POST cuja action é `index.php/busca`, esta action espera alguns dados do form, processa-os e após encontrar os produtos, faz um **redirecionamento** GET para **outra** URL, desta forma consigo evitar esta mesma situação que você descreve, pois caso o usuário clique no Voltar do navegador, não vai voltar para a action da busca.

Espero ter ajudado, ah uma dica, substituia o seu bloco `if..elseif` da modalidade por um `switch` já que as condições são todas iguais ;-) O código fica mais limpo.

Comment: Fernando, eu pensei em fazer desta forma, mas tenho receio de ter inconsistências, uma vez que eu utilizo o link para verificar se a página é a "home", a "graduação", etc. Me parece uma boa forma de se fazer. Irei testar, fazendo as devidas alterações e aviso se der certo.

Comment: Deu certo. Apesar de ser um pouco arriscado, eu criei um link com a tag <a> e enderecei o href para um link com a instrução get inclusa. Como localhost/pagina.php?instrucao=novapagina .

Comment: Legal. De forma geral eu sempre me preocupo e valido o máximo possível as URLs de actions de formulários, para evitar abusos, SQL Injection, etc. E sempre uma action após fazer a sua lógica deve redirecionar para outra URL onde o usuário acaba parando, e esta nunca é HTTP POST.